MacBook Pro 2011 is not charging
I have a MacBook Pro late 2011. It all started when my dog chewed through the magsafe charging cord. Then I wrapped the affected area with duct tape. The next day, I connected my macbook to the same charge. The red indicator lit up for 2 seconds and the macbook just went out with the magsafe plug. It didn't turn on for 5 seconds and didn't react to anything.
After 5 seconds, it turned on and booted into the system (windows 11 with all drivers). But it was no longer charging and the charging LED was not on. Then I reset the smc controller, and after that I turned it on and saw that the MacBook Windows 11 was endlessly loading and the fans were running at full power, while I pressed the battery charge check button on the left, and 8 LEDs did not light up (the macbook charge was about 11%).

Here is a photo of the gnawed place
Please tell me what it was, and if it's not about the MacBook. I have already ordered a new charger.

The new charger might help the situation, but worst-case scenario: you zapped the laptop power circuits by plugging the charger in with a mangled cable. Can't do much diagnosis from where I sit on planet Earth.


have a MacBook Pro late 2011. It all started when my dog chewed through the magsafe charging cord. Then I wrapped the affected area with duct tape.

I hope you didn't just wrap the affected area with duct tape.  First, electrical tape is much better as its nonconductive.  Duct tape can contain metalic/conductive fibers depending on the manufacturer.  Secondly, you didn't mention the state of the internal wires.  There are two shielded wires wrapped by a wire mesh that in addition to being the charger's ground/earthed conductor it acts as a noise filter.
If the insulation on the wire has been chewed off, it's very possible you shorted 18V to ground which can destroy components.  One such component is the DC-in Board or MagSafe connector.
What you should do is remove the duct tape, photograph the damaged are and post it to your question so we can accurately diagnose the issue.

Hello, I received a new charger today, I connected it and everything worked fine. The battery is charged to 100%.

@Sergey This comment is actually an answer to the original question you asked. On this (and other SE) sites, it's appropriate to answer one's own question. Thus, this comment's statement should be posed as an Answer by you, using the "Your Answer" box at the bottom.
